# Book about a "barren land" patrolled by monsters - surrounds a teleport, green disease

Tags: story-identification

I read a book 50 or so years ago. I can't remember the title or author.

Central to the plot was an area called the barren land. Monsters would occasionally wander out of the barren land. There was a village near the edge of the barren land. One of the villagers, a boy or young man, was an ash collector and soap maker. An underdog of sorts.

There was a disease or infection. It was green, I think it was called the green ague.

It is found that the barren land was put into place intentionally. It surrounded a teleport. People traveled the galaxy by teleportation through teleports, as we fly around the planet by going to an airport.

The village soap maker enters the barren land. He makes it to the center where the teleport is located. Wildlife forms wander into teleports around the galaxy. They are teleported around, occasionally arriving at the earth teleport. The "monsters".

What is the name and author of the book? I would like to read it again one day.

Comment: Hmm... the Arduin books (an early competitor to D&D) had a "green ague" disease and had a mix of fantasy and science fiction, but I haven't found anything about fiction being written from it.

Comment: Sounds a bit _Roadside Picnic_

Comment: Phil, you can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark underneath the voting buttons. If John Rennie's answer is correct, you might consider doing that (I rather suspect @AncientSwordRage is waiting on that before awarding the bounty).

Comment: Yes, Jonah, the answer was great but I'm a little unfamiliar with how this works. I'm an old man.

Comment: See? I wasn't finished, hit the enter button expecting to go to the next line but instead it "sent". I think I found the voting buttons and I think I did what I was supposed to do. If not, please let me know. I want to do whatever is expected from me by way of thanks for the correct answer.

Comment: And a big "Thank you!" to John Rennie. All this time I thought it was titled "The Barren Land" and was surprised when it wouldn't show up under that search. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks, Phil. Yes, you accepted the answer properly. Sorry if it seemed like I was putting pressure on you. We get a lot of users who just leave.

Comment: No problem! I just didn't know how it works. As I get older I reminisce over some of the old books I read as a kid. I was an avid reader of science and sci-fi books. There was another several months ago but I found it easily enough by searching "the ponics". It came up "Starship" by Brian Aldiss. "To Conquer Chaos" already showed up in the mail today. I still find it interesting, even in my old age, but "Starship" was a better written story than "To Conquer Chaos".

Comment: I put your site in my favorites list and will call on you again if memories of one of those childhood stories should creep to the surface of my brain.

Comment: And one just has! Two guys were walking down the street or a hallway chit chatting about things and it was a future earth where most citizens were armed and didn't take any crap from the bad guys. They all carried small ray guns or some kind of projected electric guns (no wires and darts involved). One of the guys was poking fun at the other guy because he was carrying an antique pistol (I think it was a 45 auto) in his holster, and he commented "Yeah, but when you kill somebody with one of those it don't even knock his hair out of place. This thing is MESSY! Scares the hell out of 'em!"

Comment: Anybody got any ideas on the name of that book?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the novel *[To Conquer Chaos](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?3284)* by John Brunner.

[image: Book cover]

The ash collector/soap maker is called Conrad:

> Grey from head to foot with wood-ash, Conrad sat by the soap-vats, in one hand his knife held by the blade close up near the point, in the other a piece of excellent soap—the hardest and whitest he had ever seen set in the shallow wooden pans.

The barren land is indeed called *barrenland*, and monsters do indeed wander out of it:

> The barrenland lay on the face of the world like an ulcer, nearly round, more than three hundred miles in circumference. It had been there so long that it was accepted; it was there and it was a fact and it was.
> ...
> The price of living there was the necessity of contending with the things that every so often wandered out of the barrenland and killed.

The disease is the *green mould* not the *green ague*. It first infects a character called Ampier, and comes from a bite by an alien beast from the barrenlands.

> Yanderman ignored the question. He said curtly, “Ampier died in the night—did you know?”
> “Of course. I was informed directly it happened; I’d given instructions.”
> “Have you seen the body?”
> “No.”
> Yanderman shuddered. “I saw it. They were carrying it out for burning as I came by. He looked as though he’d simply rotted to death. He was completely covered in that filthy green mould.”
> Duke Paul nodded. “So they told me. Obviously the beak of the thing he killed was infected, and poisoned his wound. The medics said they could find nothing that would stop the mould growing without killing the sufferer

The story is about an expedition led by Jervis Yanderman to investigate the barrenlands, so Conrad doesn't just go there on his own - he gets there as part of an expedition.

In the centre of the barrenlands is:

> The Station. It is indeed an instellar portal, but the people living there don't know how it operates. Conrad manages, quite by accident, to reactivate the portal and regain contact with the rest of galaxy.

Comment: Very nice! You'll get points, I'm sure.

Comment: @Jonah: I've been racking my brains for days over this one. It was one of those cases where the memory was in my brain somewhere but I just couldn't dig it out. Finally a switch tripped somewhere and the light bulb went on :-)

Comment: A simple search for "'barrenland' novel" would have done it. What a pity I was stuck on " 'barren land' novel."